# How to initialize column value in double dimention array for every row?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

Double dimension array initialization..

```
int[][] arr = new int[5][3];
int[0][0] = 1;
int[0][1] = 2;
int[0][2] = 3;
```

But, this is just only for `0'th` row. I want this column values for every rows. Rows may be more or more than five. I don't want to use hard coded value for every row.

Comment: E.g. in Java: `for(int i=0; i<5; i++) { for(int ii=0; ii<3; ii++) { arr[i][ii] = ii+1; } }`

Answer (score 1):

Each  entry can only have a single value, if you want to add multiple values, you need to add more code.

You are not using the correct name. The array is called `arr`, but you are setting `int`.

Your code is also missing the `arr[0][0] value`.

As it is an integer array, it will have the default value of 0. If you want to give them all the same initial value, you could loop though the values:

```
int [][] arr = new int [5][3];

for (int a = 0; a < arr.GetLength(0); a++)
{
    for (int b = 0; b < arr.GetLength(1); b++)
    {
        arr[a][b] = 123;
    }
}
```

Comment: check the edited question. Rows may be more, I can't hard code these values

Comment: What do you want the default values to be?

Comment: Question has been updated to reflect your changed question.